# Cycling through HTMl5 video tags using timeupdate and loadedmetadata events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have a web page where I am playing a series of background videos.

Initially I had it so I swap the source of the video file but I found that to be slower than having several video tags and manipulating them with display none/block.

It was working fine in all the browsers except Safari, so I started looking in a different way to fire up the videos. Before looking into using video duration and time update I simply had the "ended" event listener.

My problem with the current solution is that it doesn't work at all in Safari and stops after a couple of videos across the rest of the browsers.

Here is the code:

```js
(function ($) {
    var FIAFE = FIAFE || {};
    $.extend(true, FIAFE, {
        fanboost: {
            index: 1,
            randomize: false,
            playlist: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11'],
            video: null,
            videoDuration: null,
            bgvideo: function () {
                if (FIAFE.fanboost.video.currentTime < (FIAFE.fanboost.videoDuration - 0.5))
                {
                    console.log("currentTime is less than duration - 0.5");
                } else {
                    console.log("currentTime reached duration - 0.5");
                    if (FIAFE.fanboost.randomize) {
                        FIAFE.fanboost.index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (FIAFE.fanboost.playlist.length - 1 + 1) + 1);
                        if (FIAFE.fanboost.index >= FIAFE.fanboost.playlist.length || FIAFE.fanboost.index == 0) {
                            FIAFE.fanboost.index = 1;
                        }
                    } else {
                        FIAFE.fanboost.index++;
                        if (FIAFE.fanboost.index >= FIAFE.fanboost.playlist.length) {
                            FIAFE.fanboost.index = 1;
                            FIAFE.fanboost.randomize = true;
                        }
                    }
                    var currentVid = FIAFE.fanboost.video;
                    var newVid = document.getElementById('bgvid' + (FIAFE.fanboost.index));
                    
                    newVid.load();
                    newVid.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
                        FIAFE.fanboost.videoDuration = newVid.duration;
                        newVid.play();
                        newVid.style.display = 'block';
                        console.log("new videoDuration: " + FIAFE.fanboost.videoDuration);
                        newVid.addEventListener('timeupdate', FIAFE.fanboost.bgvideo, false);
                        newVid.removeEventListener('loadedmetadata', FIAFE.fanboost.bgvideo, false);

                        
                        currentVid.style.display = 'none';
                        currentVid.removeEventListener('timeupdate', FIAFE.fanboost.bgvideo, false);
                        FIAFE.fanboost.video = newVid;
                        
                    });
                    
                }
                    
            },
            load: function ($) {
                //Ventsi: It's not nice but will have to do for now.
                var isMobile = false;
                var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
                if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                    isMobile = true;
                }

                if (!isMobile) {
                    FIAFE.fanboost.video = document.getElementById('bgvid' + (FIAFE.fanboost.index));
                    FIAFE.fanboost.video.style.display = 'block';
                    FIAFE.fanboost.video.load();
                    FIAFE.fanboost.video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
                        FIAFE.fanboost.videoDuration = FIAFE.fanboost.video.duration;
                        FIAFE.fanboost.video.play();
                        FIAFE.fanboost.video.addEventListener('timeupdate', FIAFE.fanboost.bgvideo, false);
                        FIAFE.fanboost.video.removeEventListener('loadedmetadata', FIAFE.fanboost.bgvideo, false);
                    });
                    
                }
            }
        }
    });
    $(function () { FIAFE.fanboost.load($); });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
video.bgvid {
    position: fixed; right: 0; top: 0;
    min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <video poster="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/1.jpg" id="bgvid1" class="bgvid" muted>
        <source src="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/BEIJING1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video poster="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/2.jpg" id="bgvid2" class="bgvid" muted>
        <source src="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/BEIJING2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video poster="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/3.jpg" id="bgvid3" class="bgvid" muted>
        <source src="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/BEIJING3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video poster="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/4.jpg" id="bgvid4" class="bgvid" muted>
        <source src="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/BEIJING4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video poster="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/BUENOSAIRES1.jpg" id="bgvid5" class="bgvid" muted>
        <source src="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/BUENOSAIRES1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video poster="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/BUENOSAIRES2.jpg" id="bgvid6" class="bgvid" muted>
        <source src="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/BUENOSAIRES2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video poster="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/PUNTA2.jpg" id="bgvid7" class="bgvid" muted>
        <source src="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/PUNTA2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video poster="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/PUNTA3.jpg" id="bgvid8" class="bgvid" muted>
        <source src="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/PUNTA3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video poster="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/PUTRAJAYA1.jpg" id="bgvid9" class="bgvid" muted>
        <source src="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/PUTRAJAYA1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video poster="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/PUTRAJAYA2.jpg" id="bgvid10" class="bgvid" muted>
        <source src="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/PUTRAJAYA2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video poster="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/PUTRAJAYA3.jpg" id="bgvid11" class="bgvid" muted>
        <source src="http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/PUTRAJAYA3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

What I want to know if this should work or am I missing something and if there is a more efficient way of initiating the next video just before the previous one has loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was Safari, it was working fine across IE, Chrome and Firefox with the occasional hang up. I ended up using Ken's advice on using only 2 containers but then it was still bad in safari. Basically you'd see the video element before it actually started playing.

What sorted it out for me was adding an event listener for "playing" on the new video and within the event listener a 1 second timeout. Without the timeout, on Safari you'd still see the new video before it actually starts playing. Also I realised that switching the videos with z-index instead of display was better.

Here is the code in case someone runs into similar problem with Safari or some other browser:

```js
(function ($) {
    var FIAFE = FIAFE || {};
    $.extend(true, FIAFE, {
        fanboost: {
            index: 1,
            videoContainerId: 1,
            randomize: false,
            playlist: [
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/BEIJING1.mp4',
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/BEIJING2.mp4',
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/BEIJING3.mp4',
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/BEIJING4.mp4',
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/BUENOSAIRES1.mp4',
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/BUENOSAIRES2.mp4',
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/PUNTA2.mp4',
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/PUNTA3.mp4',
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/PUTRAJAYA1.mp4',
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/PUTRAJAYA2.mp4',
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/PUTRAJAYA3.mp4'
            ],
            playlistPosters: [
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/1.jpg',
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/2.jpg',
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/3.jpg',
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/4.jpg',
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/BUENOSAIRES1.jpg',
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/BUENOSAIRES2.jpg',
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/PUNTA2.jpg',
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/PUNTA3.jpg',
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/PUTRAJAYA1.jpg',
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/PUTRAJAYA2.jpg',
                'http://d3nqbzdvtsuedn.cloudfront.net/fbtmp/PUTRAJAYA3.jpg'
            ],
            video: null,
            videoDuration: null,
            bgvideo: function () {
                if (FIAFE.fanboost.video.currentTime < (FIAFE.fanboost.videoDuration - 1.5)) {
                    //Do Nothing
                } else {
                    if (FIAFE.fanboost.randomize) {
                        FIAFE.fanboost.index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (FIAFE.fanboost.playlist.length - 1 + 1) + 1);
                        if (FIAFE.fanboost.index > FIAFE.fanboost.playlist.length || FIAFE.fanboost.index == 0) {
                            FIAFE.fanboost.index = 1;
                        }
                    } else {
                        FIAFE.fanboost.index++;
                        if (FIAFE.fanboost.index > FIAFE.fanboost.playlist.length) {
                            FIAFE.fanboost.index = 1;
                            FIAFE.fanboost.randomize = true;
                        }
                    }

                    FIAFE.fanboost.video.removeEventListener("timeupdate", FIAFE.fanboost.bgvideo, false);
                    var newVid = document.getElementById("bgvid" + FIAFE.fanboost.videoContainerId);
                    newVid.setAttribute("poster", FIAFE.fanboost.playlistPosters[FIAFE.fanboost.index - 1]);
                    newVid.src = FIAFE.fanboost.playlist[FIAFE.fanboost.index - 1];
                    switch (FIAFE.fanboost.videoContainerId) {
                        case 1:
                            FIAFE.fanboost.videoContainerId = 2;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            FIAFE.fanboost.videoContainerId = 1;
                            break;
                    }
                    newVid.play();

                    newVid.addEventListener("playing", function listener(e) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            FIAFE.fanboost.videoDuration = newVid.duration;
                            newVid.removeEventListener("playing", listener, false);
                            FIAFE.fanboost.video.style.zIndex = "-101";
                            FIAFE.fanboost.video = null;
                            FIAFE.fanboost.video = newVid;
                            newVid = null;
                            FIAFE.fanboost.video.addEventListener("timeupdate", FIAFE.fanboost.bgvideo, false);
                            FIAFE.fanboost.video.style.zIndex = "-100";
                        }, 1000);
                    }, false);
                }
            },
            load: function ($) {
                var isMobile = false;
                var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
                if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                    isMobile = true;
                }

                if (!isMobile) {
                    FIAFE.fanboost.video = document.getElementById("bgvid" + FIAFE.fanboost.videoContainerId);
                    FIAFE.fanboost.video.setAttribute("poster", FIAFE.fanboost.playlistPosters[FIAFE.fanboost.index - 1]);
                    FIAFE.fanboost.video.style.zIndex = "-100";
                    FIAFE.fanboost.video.src = FIAFE.fanboost.playlist[FIAFE.fanboost.index - 1];
                    FIAFE.fanboost.videoContainerId = 2;
                    FIAFE.fanboost.video.play();

                    FIAFE.fanboost.video.addEventListener("playing", function listener(e) {
                        FIAFE.fanboost.videoDuration = FIAFE.fanboost.video.duration;
                        FIAFE.fanboost.video.addEventListener("timeupdate", FIAFE.fanboost.bgvideo, false);
                        FIAFE.fanboost.video.removeEventListener("playing", listener, false);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
    $(function () { FIAFE.fanboost.load($); });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
video.bgvid {
    position: fixed; right: 0; top: 0;
    min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video poster="" id="bgvid1" class="bgvid" preload="auto" muted src="">
</video>
<video poster="" id="bgvid2" class="bgvid" preload="auto" muted src="">
</video>
```

Doing it this way also got rid of the occasional crash/hang on other browsers (left the page running over the weekend on Chrome and Firefox and they were working fine when I checked it today).

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

The browser will have problems dealing with all the video elements in regards to pre-loading as well as buffering. When `preload` is not defined, it will be up to the browser to use a default.

This default is recommended to be `metadata` but this is no necessarily the case, and if it is `none`, there will be a problem getting the data in time for a gap-free playback if the next video is loaded on `ended`.

As I feel the current approach would be "wrong" in any case (spawning multiple video elements at once), I did not go into the code to debug/analyze why the videos stops.

I would rather propose the following change -

(Also, poster images are not really needed as the videos are intended to be played continuous. Removing those will help reduce some bandwidth in this case.)

## Possible solution

I would use a "double buffering" principle for this. That is, only two video elements that are toggled between.

**The process could look something like this:**

- Store all video sources in an array (randomize at will)
- Define `preload` for both elements as `metadata`, hide one and use a variable/flag to keep track of current visible element
- Start loading first video. Measure the time from `load()` to the `canplay` event is fired (store as something like `preloadtime`). Add ~10% to the time for slack and use this time to trigger pre-loading of the next video.
- Using `requestAnimationFrame`, poll the `currentTime` of the running video. When `currentTime > duration - preloadtime` set source and invoke load() on the hidden video element
- Using `requestAnimationFrame` poll the `currentTime`. When `currentTime >= duration - 33` invoke `play()` on second element, switch video element visibility. The 33 represents 2 frames, or 33ms, to reduce the gap. This is instead of using event `ended` as when `ended` is thrown the video has already stopped.
- Toggle, repeat

You can have the global variable for `preloadtime` set to -1, then update it with the max measured time (pseudo: `if (newLoadtime > preloadtime) preloadtime = newLoadtime`), or create an average for it.

You can use timeupdate event instead of requestAnimationFrame. The latter restricts the number of polls, I am not sure how much load the timeupdate events will produce as I haven't tested it.